# Can't display sqlite3 data on python

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I want to display a specific column from sqlite3 on a python Tkinter combobox, but what's displayed instead is `<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000003E73110>`, I don't know what to do? I just started coding not a while ago.

I write the following:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import  sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Library.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename (Name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL)")
combolist = c.execute("SELECT Name FROM tablename")


root = Tk()
ttk.Combobox(root, value = (combolist))
```

Comment: Try `combolist = c.fetchall()` to get the results of the call to `execute`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `execute` on a cursor object won't return you the values. Instead you can iterate over the cursor, or call `c.fetchall()` to get all of the results back together.

sqlite3 also supports a shorthand where you can call `conn.execute(...)` and get back the results directly without using an explicit cursor at all, but that requires you to call `execute` on the connection rather than the cursor.

Also you may want to unpack the name field out of each row.

I think this code should work (though I haven't tested it):

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Library.db')
with conn:
    conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename (Name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL)")
```

... more code that actually inserts some data is assumed here ...

```
with conn:
    combolist = [row["name"] for row in conn.execute("SELECT Name FROM tablename"))]
```